# Using pandas to group hierarchical data [Parent->Child] tree efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this, each have an ancestor -> parent -> child relationship.
I would like to group the data by tracing the ancestory and finding the child recursively.

```
No  Name    Ancestor MyID Parent_Id
1   Tom       191     211 111
2   Galie     191     209 111
3   Remo      434     200 101
4   Carmen    454     212 121
5   Alfred    191     111 191
6   Marvela   191     101 111
7   Armin     322     234 101
8   Boris     989     454 109
9   Katya     921     109 323
10  Adam      191     191 Null
```

For example:

Ancestory: 191 would result in the order of heiarchy:

(Grandparent -> Parent -> Child).

```
1  Adam      191     191 Null
2   Alfred    191     111 191
3   Tom       191     211 111
4   Galie     191     209 111
5   Marvela   191     101 111
```

My approach (without using pandas) was to first find the unique ancestors in the column (Ancestor), and then loop through each unique item in the list using a for loop and recursively go through each to find the children.
This worked well, but the dataframe has about 100K entires and a for loop was getting expensive.

What would be the best way to use pandas to solve this without having to use expensive iterative for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this result looks like you desired:

```
df_source = pd.read_excel('data8.xlsx', index_col = 'No')
df_source['Parent_Id'] = pd.to_numeric(df_source['Parent_Id'], errors = 'coerce').fillna(-1)

df_p = df_source[df_source['Parent_Id'] == -1]
df_p.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1],df_source.columns])

df = df_source.copy()
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2],df_source.columns])

step = 2
while True:

    df_p = df_p.merge(df, how = 'left', left_on = [(step-1,'MyID')], right_on = [(step,'Parent_Id')])

    step+=1
    df = df_source.copy()
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[step],df_source.columns])
    if len(set(df_p[(step-1,'MyID')]).intersection(set(df[(step,'Parent_Id')]))) == 0: break


Out[1]:

    1                               2                                       3                                       4
    Name Ancestor MyID  Parent_Id   Name    Ancestor    MyID    Parent_Id   Name    Ancestor    MyID    Parent_Id   Name    Ancestor    MyID    Parent_Id
0   Adam    191   191     -1.0      Alfred     191      111      191.0      Tom     191         211       111.0     NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN
1   Adam    191   191     -1.0      Alfred     191      111      191.0      Galie   191         209       111.0     NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN
2   Adam    191   191     -1.0      Alfred     191      111      191.0      Marvela 191         101       111.0     Remo       434.0    200.0    101.0
3   Adam    191   191     -1.0      Alfred     191      111      191.0      Marvela 191         101       111.0     Armin      322.0    234.0    101.0
```

## by steps:

```
Out[1]:

        1
    Name    Ancestor    MyID    Parent_Id
No              
10  Adam       191      191        -1.0


Out[2]:

        1                                   2
    Name    Ancestor    MyID    Parent_Id   Name    Ancestor    MyID    Parent_Id
0   Adam       191      191       -1.0      Alfred     191       111    191.0


Out[3]:

    1                                       2                                       3
    Name    Ancestor    MyID    Parent_Id   Name    Ancestor    MyID    Parent_Id   Name    Ancestor    MyID    Parent_Id
0   Adam       191      191      -1.0       Alfred     191      111     191.0       Tom      191        211        111.0
1   Adam       191      191      -1.0       Alfred     191      111     191.0       Galie    191        209        111.0
2   Adam       191      191      -1.0       Alfred     191      111     191.0       Marvela  191        101        111.0
```